# Are there any languages which use "object literal" as simple as Javascript?

Tags: arrays, object, syntax

Object literal are very useful in Javascript :

```
var obj = {key1: 321};
obj.key1 = 123
```

But it's just a way to organize data. Every language provides its own data structures, and I think that everything that can be done with object literal, can also be done with the majority of programming languages.

But are there any other languages which allow object literal creation without extra words (array, cast, object, ...) ?

Comment: That's called an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has anonymous types:

```
var myObject = new { Prop1 = 2, Prop2 = "abc" };
```